# Disable SSIS tasks programatically in c# custom application

Tags: c#, winforms, ssis

I am building a windows forms application that executes selected packages and all the packages send mails. I would like to add the option to let the user 
disable send mail task for the selected packages.

Im am using vs 2015 integration services to build the packages.

The code for executing the packages:

```
        string pkgLocation = @" C:\temp\Testing\"+ PackageName + ".dtsx";
        Package Package = new Package();
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app;           
        DTSExecResult res;


        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();

        PackageEvents packageEvents = new PackageEvents();
        Package.EnableConfigurations = true;
        Package = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, packageEvents);

        res = Package.Execute();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

        if (res == DTSExecResult.Success)
        {
           //code
        }
        else if (res == DTSExecResult.Failure)
        {
           //code
        }
```

Is it posible to disable a task from the application?

Comment: Should I just answer Yes? Can you provide some code and/or some samples.

Comment: Yes. Add a parameter to your package that decides whether emails are sent and use the parameter. Your question has nowhere enough detail. What version of SSIS? What does your code look like?

Comment: I have uploaded the code that executes the packages. Can you give a exaple of manipulating parameters via code. i alredy have a variable that is suplied to the mail task.

Comment: A bit of googling turned up this code for setting parmeters https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21978.execute-ssis-2012-package-with-parameters-via-net.aspx but first you have to alter the package to include the parameter and act on it

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution on the net. It is very simple. I itterated through all Executables that are in the package and if the task is the one i am looking for set the disable property to false. Here is the code below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Package.Executables.Count; i++)
    {
     if ((TaskHost)Package.Executables[i] == (TaskHost)Package.Executables["Send Mail Task"])
         {
            var task = (TaskHost)Package.Executables["Send Mail Task"];
            task.Properties["Disable"].SetValue(task, true);
            break;
         }
     }
```

Thank you for your help.